# Installing Ubuntu Server 16.04 on Vmware

Tags: filesystem, root, vmware, ext3

I am installing Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine on an Intel server using vmware.

For some reason, it is creating the root file system as ext4 but I NEED it to be ext3. 
Is this possible? I have been through the installation a couple of times but I was not prompted or given the option to choose the file system which is rather odd.

Your support is appreciated.

Thanks,
Asif.

Comment: You would have to do manual partitioning to get ext3 working - ext4 is the "standard" Ubuntu filesystem type nowadays.

Comment: Can you expand on this? This is the exact reason why I opened this question. I need to know how to install Ubuntu using vmware and have the root file system on ext3 not ext4. This is needed to install a certain database which will not work with ext4.

Comment: That must be some really damn odd database then.  It is too difficult to explain without screenshots so give me some time to compile a few.  (This isn't a VMware unique issue though - but if you use easy install it won't work so I'll include VMware parts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Note:** This will not work if "Easy Install" option in VMware is used, which will automatically set up Ubuntu with a default set of settings. When prompted to create the Virtual Machine, select the Ubuntu version in the OS type, but don't specify the ISO and use "I will install the operating system later", do not automatically power up the VM, and edit the VM to use the ISO, then boot to the ISO and manually do system setup as detailed below.

I'll walk you through the manual partition manager for Ubuntu Server.

Initially it is the same install, I'll assume you have gotten that far.

Once you get to this screen, select "Manual":

[image: Manual Partitioning]

This next part depends on how you want to install, however due to you using VMWare we will use the full disk. (**Note:** This is for a single partition install, if you plan to have multiple partitions, e.g. One for "/" and another for "/home" then you will need more partitions)

Okay, here is where things get interesting. In manual mode, you have to do a bit more to get the same job done. Though ensure you follow these steps precisely.

1. First things first, create the partition table.

[image: Create the table]

You should see something like below, select yes.

[image: Building empty table]

2. Build your partitions.

Select your new partition table.

[image: New Partition Table]

This should bring up a new menu. To save you the hassle of adding swap partitions select "Automatically partition the free space"

[image: Auto Partition]

This will bring you back to the previous menu, select the "Ext4" partition.

[image: Partitions List]

This should bring up the partition's menu, select "Use as:".

[image: Partition Menu]

Then select "Ext3 journaling file system"

[image: Ext3 Yay]

Then select done in the previous menu, and then finish in the Manual partitioning menu. Then continue on with your installation! Hope I've been helpful.

Josh

Comment: Make a note at the beginning that if 'Easy Install' (a VMware feature) is used, this will not work.

Comment: Glad I could be some use! I don't know much about "Easy Install" as I use Virtualbox/KVM, hopefully this is sufficient.

Comment: I made some tweaks, indicating the fact it won't work, and how to get around it, in a small quote box  :)

Comment: Hi Josh, Many thanks - that was very useful, and got the job done. I am trying to install sap hana database on Ubuntu (officially supported on Suse & RH only), and the installer complained that the ext4 was unsupported :S. Anyways, many thanks for your help!